# Error while logging in with Microsoft in Flutter using Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to log the user in with Microsoft in Flutter. This is the code I wrote

```
signInWithMicrosoft() async {
    final microsoftProvider = MicrosoftAuthProvider();
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);
  }
```

Its working but after putting my credentials I am getting a Unhandled Exception.
This is the error I am getting

[image]